# what is workers parameter in word2vec in NLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

in below code .
i didn't understand the meaning of workers parameter .
model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=300000, window=2, min_count=5, workers=4)

Comment: `workers` is the number of threads for the training of the model, higher number = faster training.

Comment: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.trainables - http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a case of RTFM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

workers = use this many worker threads to train the model (=faster training with multicore machines).

If your system is having 2 cores, and if you specify workers=2, then data will be trained in two parallel ways.

By default , worker = 1 i.e,  no parallelization

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `workers` controls the number of independent threads doing simultaneous training.

In general, you'll never want to use more workers than the number of CPU cores.

But further, the gensim `Word2Vec` implementation faces a bit more thread-to-thread bottlenecking due to issues like the Python "Global Interpreter Lock" ('GIL') and some of its IO/corpus-handling design decisions.

So on systems with a large number of cores, such as more than 16, the optimal `workers` value for maximum throughput is usually less than the full count of cores – often in the 3-12 range. (The exact number will depend on other aspects of your corpus-handling and chosen metaparameters, and for now is most often discovered through trial-and-error.)

If your corpus is already in a specific text format, the latest gensim release, 3.6.0, offers a new input mode that allows better scaling of `workers` all the way up to the count of CPU cores. See [this section of the release notes about the new `corpus_file` parameter](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/7e4965ee6c9d4e200dae6fb089b46c2ebc27e159/CHANGELOG.md#star2-new-features) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [effective_n_jobs](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/c0e0169565116854993b22efef29e3c402ec6c69/gensim/utils.py#L2105) to determine the correct use of the number of threads in your case.

```
from gensim.utils import effective_n_jobs

effective_n_jobs(1)
effective_n_jobs(-1)
effective_n_jobs(None)
effective_n_jobs(12)
effective_n_jobs(10)

# outputs
1
12
1
12
10
```