# what does workers means in gensim Word2Vec?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to create a Word2Vec model using gensim but I don't understand what Workers mean.
This is an examples from radimrehurek.com with `workers = 4` but there is no explanation for that.

`Word2Vec(sentences=common_texts, vector_size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)`

I would be very thankful of anyone can help me.Thxx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is workers parameter in word2vec in NLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417258/what-is-workers-parameter-in-word2vec-in-nlp)

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of Python worker threads that will be used during the training phase.

If you're using the traditional iterable-of-texts (like your `sentences` parameter) to supply your corpus, and you're on a machine with at least 4 CPU cores, you'll usually get the best throughput with a `workers` value of at least 3, and *perhaps* as high as 8-12 (but never higher than the number of CPU cores minus one).

If your input is a plain text file, with tokens already whitespace-delimited, and individual newline-delimited texts of no more than 10000-tokens each, you can use the more-recently introduced `corpus_file` option to specify the corpus. In that case, you are likely to achieve maximum training throughput with `workers` equal to the number of available CPU cores.

(You can get the number of cores with `import multiprocessing` then `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.)

Comment: Thank you very much. That’s a perfect answer.

Comment: @gojomo what if I use 'PathLineSentences' in gensim to stream files from a directory. All my files conform to PathLineSentence format. But, the training is not happening in parallel. Every time a file is opened for training, the log shows 'in_qsize 0, out_qsize 0' and processes as many words there are in a file, making the entire process painfully slow.

Comment: Normally there's no problem achieving multihreaded training with that `PathLineSentences` iterable, since one thread is doing that reading, and `workers` count other threads are handling the texts. If you think you're seeing that, you should post a separate question with the full code/output/problem details of your situation. (`in_qsize 0, out_qsize 0` isn't necessarily an indication of any problem - it means the threas are all keeping up with the workload just fine - but slowness might have many causes.)